# How to make JMeter wait for a page answer

Tags: web-services, jmeter, httpresponse, load-testing, performance-testing

I was not able to figure out how to make JMeter wait for HTTP Response from Web Service.
I added If Controller with `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` option, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Oliver response.

But maybe your question is too vague and what you are trying to do is wait for some response following an intermediate "loading page", in this case answer would be something like this:

- http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/waiting-for-a-page-change-in-jmeter

Answer (score 2):

JMeter waits for a HTTP response by default.

If you're using the [HTTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) then you can view the response for each request using the [View Results Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree). You can also set the timeout for requests in the sampler itself or by using the [HTTP Defaults Control](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).